# Tablet apps sounds does not work anymore

Tags: audio, tablet

This morning I was listening music using grooveshark and the speakers of a Pantech P4100 Tablet. the player stopped playing.

Now -even after restarting and resetting to factory settings-, only the notifications and alarms make sound. the apps do not sound.

Nonetheless, if I plug my headphones it works (appsm notifications and alarms)

#### How can I fix the integrated speaker sounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because the OS thinks you connected your headphones. I saw that problem in iOS some years ago. Use this app to solve it: [WiredHeadphoneRoutingFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix)