# Why does my sound randomly stop working?

Tags: cyanogenmod, audio, motorola-droid-razr

I have a rather old Motorola Droid Razr Maxx.  A week or so ago it was having some serious problems which rendered it fairly useless, so I installed CyanogenMod on it.

Since then, sound will randomly completely stop from all sources.  Various apps, music, even phone calls.  Nada.

I'm fairly certain this is a software issue as the sound worked fine before flashing CyanogenMod and a reboot temporarily fixes the problem (and is so far the only solution I've found).

I'm fairly sure it doesn't have to do with the [headphone state](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27327/tablet-apps-sounds-does-not-work-anymore) as neither speaker nor headphones works when the sound is broken, yet both work immediately after a reboot.

Constantly rebooting my phone so I can actually receive calls is rather sub-optimal.  What can I do?

Comment: As a side note, I suppose I *could* theoretically go back to stock, but, aside from this problem, I'm vastly preferring CM, so I'd like to stick with it if possible.

Comment: What CM ROM have you used? If it's a nightly, you might have to replace it with the latest stable release, or just wait for the bug to be fixed in a later release.

Comment: @DanHulme I'm using 10.2.1 which [appears to be both stable and the latest version for my device](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=spyder&type=stable).